# MultiThreaded Fibonacci

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

```
public class Fibonacci {

public static class PFibo extends Thread {
    private int x;
    public long answer;

    public PFibo(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (x <= 2)
            answer = 1;
        else {
            try {
                PFibo t = new PFibo(x - 1);
                t.start();

                long y = RFibo(x - 2);

                t.join();
                answer = t.answer + y;

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}

public static long RFibo(int no) {
    if (no == 1 || no == 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return RFibo(no - 1) + RFibo(no - 2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        PFibo f = new PFibo(30);
        f.start();
        f.join();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Parallel-Fibonacci:" + f.answer + "\tTime:" + (end - start));

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long result = RFibo(30);
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Normal-Fibonacci:" + result + "\tTime:" + (end - start));


    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

}

I am currently reading 'Multithreaded Algorithms' from 'Introduction to Algorithms'. I tried implementing a basic multithreaded program for calculating the n-th fibonacci number. For n=30 the program gave the following output :

```
Parallel-Fibonacci:832040   Time:10
Normal-Fibonacci:832040     Time:3
```

Why is the parallel version slower that the non-parallel version. Has thread-switching or 'too-many-number-of-threads' slowed it down ?

What approach has to followed to speed-up the parallel version ?

Comment: You appear to be creating a new thread every loop. That's going to cost you.

Comment: Also since Fibonacci is a *sequence* it doesn't really make sense to multi thread it. Every value depends on the previous ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has thread-switching or 'too-many-number-of-threads' slowed it down ?

Yes of course. In a number of ways-

As already been pointed out in comments

1. You are creating a new thread per call i.e.

    `PFibo t = new PFibo(x - 1);
               t.start();`

Effectively you have created around 28 threads for `PFibo(30)` which means **one context switch for evaluating each term**

2. Secondly, as the evaluation of PFibo(x) depends on PFibo(x - 1) which required you to put a call to `join()` method there, each time you are creating/starting a new thread i.e. eventually it has become serial.

So the **final cost** =  cost of actual serial method `RFibo(n)` + around n context switches + sync time (time taken by `join()`)

> What approach has to followed to speed-up the parallel version ?

Well I would say, don't do it. Fibonacci series' solution pattern does not suit to be optimized by parallelism. Just rely on serial version(you can implement an iterative version for more efficiency).

Comment: Put in a counting mechanism for every `PFibo` instantiated/started - I think `28` is on the low side.

Answer (score 0):

your input is too small to gain any benefit from parallelism. Nevertheless, it makes sense to parallelize *this* version of the Fibonacci algorithm. Your algorithm is exponential. By creating new threads, you split exponential work among the threads. Notice, however, that there is, indeed, a linear-time algorithm to compute the Fibonacci numbers, which, as people here have already said, it is better to run sequentially. So, using larger inputs with your implementation, I get, on an Intel 2.3GHz:

```
$ java Fib 30
Parallel-Fib:832040     Time:0.026805616
Sequential-Fib:832040   Time:0.002786453

$ java Fib 33
Parallel-Fib:3524578    Time:0.012451416
Sequential-Fib:3524578  Time:0.012420652

$ java Fib 36
Parallel-Fib:14930352   Time:0.035997556
Sequential-Fib:14930352 Time:0.056066557

$ java Fib 44
Parallel-Fib:701408733   Time:2.037292083
Sequential-Fib:701408733 Time:3.050315551
```